# How can I set up IBM Http Server on WAS ND traditional in Bluemix

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-was-oc

I am trying out the application deployment in WAS ND Bluemix (1 DMgr and IHS + 1 Custom Node). I am able to successfully deploy application, but unable to configure the web server to route the requests. Any pointers or steps will really help!

Answer (score 2):

The WebSphere Application Server for Bluemix Network Deployment Plan consists of a WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment cell environment with two or more virtual machines. The first virtual machine contains the deployment manager and IBM HTTP Server and the remaining virtual machines contain custom nodes (node agents) federated to the deployment manager. You can use your existing wsadmin scripts to create your WebSphere configuration or use the WebSphere Admin Console to manually configure the environment.

For more information I suggest you to take a look at [Overview of WebSphere Application Server for Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ApplicationServeronCloud/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Bill, You need to configure the plugin to the IBM HTTP Server (IHS).  See this WebSphere Knowledge Center article for details:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twsv_plugin.html?lang=en